# The responsiveness of images side by side

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

Looking at it here:
https://www.hq.vevo.com/watch

How would I replicate that?

When the site window gets bigger and smaller, how that causes the images to expand and get smaller.

This is as far as I got: https://jsfiddle.net/2kbv3jzg/2/

It goes from this:

[image]

to this:

That is how it looks on the website.

I'm trying to replicate that.

[image]

Can someone replicate that for me, how that is done?

Would someone be able to create a code example of how that is done?

```
<div id="comp-l5cpy8ul1" class="Mdue19 comp-l5cpy8ul1 wixui-repeater">
  <div class="comp-l5cpy8ul1-container" data-testid="responsive-container-content" role="list">
    <div id="comp-l5cpy8v01__0b5cd8bd-cb20-42b0-8939-4530690dbbf3" role="listitem" class="QOX0dS JCRlLH comp-l5cpy8v01-container comp-l5cpy8v01 wixui-repeater__item">
      <div class="AG_P7Z MAs5Tr wixui-repeater__item"></div>
      <div id="comp-l5cpy8vb2__0b5cd8bd-cb20-42b0-8939-4530690dbbf3" data-testid="imageX" class="Byppxy comp-l5cpy8vb2 wixui-image"><a data-testid="linkElement" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VronettmNRI" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="L4tPY9 has-custom-focus">
          <wix-image id="img-comp-l5cpy8vb2__0b5cd8bd-cb20-42b0-8939-4530690dbbf3" data-image-info="{&quot;containerId&quot;:&quot;comp-l5cpy8vb2__0b5cd8bd-cb20-42b0-8939-4530690dbbf3&quot;,&quot;alignType&quot;:&quot;center&quot;,&quot;parallaxSpeed&quot;:1.5,&quot;sourceSets&quot;:[],&quot;imageData&quot;:{&quot;uri&quot;:&quot;d5da94_e29932e9ef8545f0bbc9322d109a9fab~mv2.jpg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:3000,&quot;height&quot;:963,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Ariana Grande &amp; The Weeknd&quot;,&quot;displayMode&quot;:&quot;fill&quot;,&quot;focalPoint&quot;:{&quot;x&quot;:49,&quot;y&quot;:31},&quot;scrollEffect&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;OLPalt_edited.jpg&quot;,&quot;crop&quot;:null}}" data-has-ssr-src="" class="AXsuhY" data-src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d5da94_e29932e9ef8545f0bbc9322d109a9fab~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_612,h_300,fp_0.49_0.31,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/OLPalt_edited.jpg">
            <picture><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d5da94_e29932e9ef8545f0bbc9322d109a9fab~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_612,h_300,fp_0.49_0.31,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/OLPalt_edited.jpg" alt="Ariana Grande &amp; The Weeknd" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 49% 31%; width: 100%;" fetchpriority="high"></picture>
          </wix-image>
        </a></div>
      <div id="comp-l5cpy8vi__0b5cd8bd-cb20-42b0-8939-4530690dbbf3" class="QOX0dS JCRlLH comp-l5cpy8vi-container comp-l5cpy8vi wixui-box">
        <div class="AG_P7Z MAs5Tr wixui-box"></div>

        <div id="comp-l5cpy8v01__263beb80-066a-422e-9212-2a5ec523f6dc" role="listitem" class="QOX0dS JCRlLH comp-l5cpy8v01-container comp-l5cpy8v01 wixui-repeater__item">
      <div class="AG_P7Z MAs5Tr wixui-repeater__item"></div>
      <div id="comp-l5cpy8vb2__263beb80-066a-422e-9212-2a5ec523f6dc" data-testid="imageX" class="Byppxy comp-l5cpy8vb2 wixui-image"><a data-testid="linkElement" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsT1it_dObI" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="L4tPY9 has-custom-focus">
          <wix-image id="img-comp-l5cpy8vb2__263beb80-066a-422e-9212-2a5ec523f6dc" data-image-info="{&quot;containerId&quot;:&quot;comp-l5cpy8vb2__263beb80-066a-422e-9212-2a5ec523f6dc&quot;,&quot;alignType&quot;:&quot;center&quot;,&quot;parallaxSpeed&quot;:1.5,&quot;sourceSets&quot;:[],&quot;imageData&quot;:{&quot;uri&quot;:&quot;d5da94_0a0d5057e60f4fc5a41f2db6a1ab8501~mv2.jpg&quot;,&quot;width&quot;:1920,&quot;height&quot;:652,&quot;alt&quot;:&quot;Lil Baby&quot;,&quot;displayMode&quot;:&quot;fill&quot;,&quot;focalPoint&quot;:{&quot;x&quot;:49,&quot;y&quot;:31},&quot;scrollEffect&quot;:&quot;none&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;CTRL_edited.jpg&quot;,&quot;crop&quot;:null}}" data-has-ssr-src="" class="AXsuhY" data-src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d5da94_0a0d5057e60f4fc5a41f2db6a1ab8501~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_612,h_300,fp_0.49_0.31,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/CTRL_edited.jpg">
            <picture><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/d5da94_0a0d5057e60f4fc5a41f2db6a1ab8501~mv2.jpg/v1/fill/w_612,h_300,fp_0.49_0.31,q_80,usm_0.66_1.00_0.01,enc_auto/CTRL_edited.jpg" alt="Lil Baby" style="object-fit: cover; object-position: 49% 31%; width: 100%;" fetchpriority="high"></picture>
          </wix-image>
        </a></div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I can see, the image is resized on the server side then it goes responsive, when you change the resolution, the URL of the image changes to fit the new size. You can check CSS aspect ratio property.

Comment: Would someone be able to make a jsfiddle snippet of how that is all done?

Comment: This is not a good way to achieve it to be honest. Resizing on the fly your images need good infrastructure to avoid performances leak. Check about some css property to keep images ratio. You'll find resources on internet